# Excel VBA paste rows one after other

Tags: excel, vba

The idea here is to copy rows from one sheet `Samples` to a specific place in sheet `MainTable`. It works fine but I can only add on the beginning of the sheet in other words only on the mentioned range. When I press the button I want it to appear in the beginning, or if there is already one product - after that one and so on. This is the code:

```
Sub AddProduct()


AddProduct Macro
  Sheets("Samples").Select
   Rows("1:11").Select
   Range("N1").Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Copy

  Sheets("MainTable").Select
   Range("12:22").Select
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

Basically the range where the content needs to go should be: Range("12:22")->Range("23:33")->Range("34:44") and so on, depending on existing products...

I thought of a possible solution but I don't know how to do it:

If I add a hidden letter `x` in column V, in range from sheet `Samples`, than I can do `COUNTIF` to that column. The number of `x`es will tell me how many products I have added in `MainTable`.

Then I put this code in an empty space in `MainTable` (in this case O5,P5):

O5:
`=11*COUNTIF(V:V;"x")+12`

P5:
`=11*COUNTIF(V:V;"x")+22`

Now the part I don't know:

```
...
Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Copy

Sheets("MainTable").Select
   Range("O5.Value:P5.Value").Select
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

   End Sub
```

How can I achieve this? Getting values from Cells O5 and P5 into VBA

Comment: Countless examples online on finding last used row. Are you inserting because you have data below where you are pasting?

Comment: Sphinx solved my problem, thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...    
Dim StartRow as long, EndRow as long 

StartRow = Range("O5").value  
EndRow = Range("P5").value
Range(StartRow & ":" & EndRow).Select
....
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!